Expiring coupons in EE
I've created an extension to programmatically add coupons that expire in 24 hrs (more or less).
All is working on Community version. My problem is with EE.
Checking the docs it seems that, on EE, the expiration date has been replaced by scheduled updates.
It is actually possible to create a scheduled update programmatically but, as my module is supposed to work for both Communtiy and EE edition, I would probably need to check for schedule update existence before adding the coupon. It is a bit tricky and prone to errors.
Also it seems a waste to add an update for each coupon, as each is usable only once.
My question is... even if not shown in admin UI, are salesrule.start_date and salesrule.end_date still used in EE? if not, is salesrule_coupon.expiration_date field actually used in EE?
I'm not interested that the expiration date is visible into the backend, only that the coupon is no longer valid after the expiration.
Does anyone know the answer?

yes, checking on the magento-salesrules-staging which is available for EE, the start_date is used on the schedule process. So basically, the module uses the field to update it on schedule.
  <field name="staging_save_start_date" class="Magento\Staging\Block\Adminhtml\Update\Entity\Create\StartTime" formElement="date">

This is on the salesrulestaging_update_form.xml which triggers the staging sidebar element.
Having the module to detect if the Magento_SalesRuleStaging exists would allow you to act based on that.

Hi, thanks.
I'm not sure if I understand your answer.
I can detect if the module exists, so this is something but, if I leave my logic as it is, adding both the expiration time to the rule and the coupon, will it still work in EE or do I need to create a scheduled update also to have the coupon expire in 24 hrs? I can see it in the coupon model.
/** * Get expiration date
* return string|null
* deprecated 101.1.3 Coupon expiration must follow sales rule expiration date.
*/ public function getExpirationDate()
{ return $this->getData(self::KEY_EXPIRATION_DATE); }

The code you see indicates that the expiration date on the coupon is been removed, not on the rule. For EE, you will need to create a schedule to disable the rule. On non-EE you can manage that with your current setup.
